# F# ASync.Parallel plus main thread

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have an F# program to copy files that I want to work asynchronously.  So far I have:

```
let asyncFileCopy (source, target, overwrite) =
    let copyfn (source,target,overwrite) =
        printfn "Copying %s to %s" source target
        File.Copy(source, target, overwrite)
        printfn "Copyied %s to %s" source target
    let fn = new Func<string * string * bool, unit>(copyfn)
    Async.FromBeginEnd((source, target, overwrite), fn.BeginInvoke, fn.EndInvoke)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let copyfile1 = asyncFileCopy("file1", "file2", true)
    let copyfile2 = asyncFileCopy("file3", "file4", true)

    let asynctask =
        [copyfile1; copyfile2] 
        |> Async.Parallel 

    printfn "doing other stuff"

    Async.RunSynchronously asynctask |> ignore
```

which works (the files are copied) but not in the way I want.  I want to start the parallel copy operations so that they begin copying.  Meanwhile, I want to continue doing stuff on the main thread.  Later, I want to wait for the asynchronous tasks to complete.  What my code seems to do is set up the parallel copies, then do other stuff, but not actually execute the copies until it hits Async.Runsychronously.

Is there a way to, in effect, Async.Run"a"synchronously, to get the copies started in the thread pool, then do other stuff and later wait for the copies to finish?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out:

```
 let asynctask =
    [copyfile1; copyfile2] 
    |> Async.Parallel 
    |> Async.StartAsTask

let result = Async.AwaitIAsyncResult asynctask

printfn "doing other stuff"

Async.RunSynchronously result |> ignore
printfn "Done"
```

The key is using StartAsTask, AwaitIAsyncResult and only later RunSynchronously to await task completion

Comment: Once 48 hours have passed since you asked your question, you'll be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkbox under its score. (The system requires you to wait 48 hours because other people *might* also answer it, with answers that turn out to be even better than yours.) Once you're able to accept your own answer, you should do so, since that gives it a different color in search results and lets other people know that if they click on this question, they will see an answer that solved the question. (Something very nice to know when you're searching for the answer yourself!)